How can I determine the exact creation time of a frame from an RTSP stream?
I have a Python script that detects objects in the video stream from an LTV-3CNB50-M0560 IP camera. Currently, an RTSP stream is being used. When an object is detected in the frame, it turns out that the current time is behind the real event time, i.e., the moment when the camera generated the frame, by a random amount. I need to know the exact time of the frame, and thus the exact time of the event. Right now, I plan to use Tesseract to recognize the timestamp on the video overlay, but this approach doesn't seem rational. What's the best way to solve this problem?

Why you not just easy create a timestamp when you recv. the frame and pass this also to your detection. You will need to create the timestamp before your detection. I Wonder why this is an issue gg

@Christoph, Yes, that’s how I originally did it. I obtain the timestamp immediately after:

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
some code #
while cap.isOpened():
ret, frame = cap.read()
frame_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'

However, the frame_time is still delayed by about 0.7 to 1.6 seconds from the actual event time. I consider the actual event time to be the timestamp value embedded on the video overlay.

So you had configured a time overlay in your camera? Did you also had latency of 0.7 sec?

@Christoph I synchronized the time on the camera and server using a dedicated NTP server. I used the camera's On Screen Display function to show the timestamp in the frame. When I open the frame's JPG and compare the time shown in the frame with the frame_time, I see a random delay ranging from 0.7 to 1.6 seconds.

Thats normal because it takes time to decode it. If you want more percision you need to use ffmpeg and use the packet as reference. You can use the pyav package is great and you can port the code Into 10 Minutes but you will also had an short delay because of Network. The closed Would be ntp timestamps from the rtp packages but this must your camera Support. At end think about how many time you Would Invest for 1 second off. Who cares If the bad guy stole my Car at 14:15:10 or 14:15:11 gg

@Christoph, thank you. I am working on a vehicle classification subsystem for a freeflow toll road. In my case, it is very important to send the most accurate time value so that colleagues can match data from various sources – the license plate recognition subsystem, axle counters, and others. This is especially critical when several vehicles are driving very close to each other. Our system is not real-time, so the very fact of delay is unpleasant but can be addressed during post-processing before sending. I am currently using Tesseract. Next, I’ll explore pyav – it looks interesting.
